# Why would Oracle.ManagedDataAccess not work when Oracle.DataAccess does?

Tags: c#, oracle, tnsnames

I'm developing a very simple application which I intend to use to troubleshoot an issue I am having on a few machines but before I even got that far I ran into a few issues, including cpu architecture differences and Oracle database libraries.

I have a database server listed in `tnsnames.ora`, sitting in my `C:\oracle\11g\network\admin` directory. If I tnsping this server I get the desired response. If I code my C# program to connect to this server with the following code using Oracle.DataAccess.Client, it works.

```
string connectionString = "Data Source=DSDSDS;User Id=UNUNUN;Password=PWPWPW;";
DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();

using (var connection = new OracleConnection(connectionString)) {
    connection.Open();
    using (var command = new OracleCommand()) {
        command.Connection = connection;
        command.CommandText = sql;
        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        using (var oda = new OracleDataAdapter(command)) {
            oda.Fill(dataTable);
        }
    }
}
```

However Oracle.DataAccess is dependent on the architecture of the system it runs on. I saw that there is another library Oracle.ManagedDataAccess which is architecture independent. When I use this library it no longer is able to connect to the server. An `ORA-12545: Network Transport: Unable to resolve connect hostname` is thrown.

Why is this the case? What is different between these two libraries because based upon what I've read thus far this shouldn't be an issue.

Extra information:

- %ORACLE_HOME% and %TNS_ADMIN% are NOT defined (remember that tnsping and Oracle.DataAccess work)
- PATH has `C:\oracle\11g\BIN` defined.
- My machine only has one `tnsnames.ora` file

If I move tnsnames.ora to the same location as my .exe file, it works. Why can Oracle.DataAccess find tnsnames.ora in the `C:\oracle\11g\network\admin` directory but Oracle.ManagedAccess cannot?

Comment: I'm actually having the same issue, regardless of TNS_ADMIN settings in app.config.

Comment: You  resolve this ? Can you explain me ?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

The order of precedence for resolving TNS names in ODP.NET, Managed Driver is this (see [here](https://forums.oracle.com/message/10610812#10610812)):

1. data source alias in the 'dataSources' section under  section in the .NET config file.
2. data source alias in the tnsnames.ora file at the location specified by 'TNS_ADMIN' in the .NET config file.
3. data source alias in the tnsnames.ora file present in the same directory as the .exe.
4. data source alias in the tnsnames.ora file present at %TNS_ADMIN% (where %TNS_ADMIN% is an environment variable setting).
5. data source alias in the tnsnames.ora file present at %ORACLE_HOME%\network\admin (where %ORACLE_HOME% is an environment variable setting).

I believe the reason your sample works with Oracle.DataAccess but not with Oracle.ManagedDataAccess is that Windows registry based configuration is not supported for the latter (see [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E48297_01/doc/win.121/e41125/featConfig.htm)) - the ODP.NET installation sets an ORACLE_HOME registry key (HLKM\SOFTWARE\Oracle\Key_NAME\ORACLE_HOME) which is recognized only by the unmanaged part.

Comment: Ok well that certainly clears the air a bit. However my latest issue was "Unrecognized configuration section oracle.manageddataaccess.client". Looks like "<configSections><section name="oracle.manageddataaccess.client" type="OracleInternal.Common.ODPMSectionHandler, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess" /></configSections>" is needed as well.

Comment: It definitely works without it (verified on tens of installations both desktop and web). However, if you use this, make sure that assembly signature (version number, public key etc) in configSections/section@type corresponds exactly with Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll you use.

Comment: great explanation thanks. In the production environment I just added the key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Oracle\ODP.NET.Managed\4.121.2.0 and added a string value TNS_ADMIN pointing to the tnsnames.ora

Comment: Since my connection string uses `providerName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client` I had to copy client files from my local  `C:\oracle\product\12.2.0\dbhome_1\ODP.NET\managed` into the server's oracle installation `C:\ORACLE\product\11.2.0\client_2\ODP.NET` which did not have managed data access. Then on target server I had to run `C:\oracle\product\12.2.0\dbhome_1\ODP.NET\managed\x86\configure.bat`. TNS_ADMIN was set as system environment variable. Now IIS on target server is serving web application correctly.

Comment: NOTE: The TNS_ADMIN setting in the config file  `<setting name="TNS_ADMIN" value="tns_file_location"/>` requires Oracle.ManagedDataAccess version 19.3 or above. It does not work in 18.3 or 18.6 (not sure about other lower versions). I am on Oracle 12c, so that may also be in play.

Answer (score 19):

Try to add the path to tnsnames.ora to the config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
    <version number="4.112.3.60">
      <settings>
        <setting name="TNS_ADMIN" value="C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\client_1\NETWORK\ADMIN\" />
      </settings>
    </version>
  </oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
</configuration>
```

Comment: If TNS_ADMIN has the correct value then a problem might be in version number. Try to use <version number="*">

Comment: I'm doing that. It would be lovely if one programmatically could see both the tnsnames and sqlnet in use ;) I'm using the production version 121.1.0 released a couple of days ago. But thanks anyhow! :)

Comment: I gave this a try but I am unsuccessful. I changed the path to C:\oracle\11g\network\admin\ per my setup, but I am receiving: A first chance exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'OracleInternal.Common.ProviderConfig' threw an exception. ---> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Configuration system failed to initialize ---> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Unrecognized configuration section oracle.manageddataaccess.client.

Comment: The setting above finally has fixed my problem in a c# project after have installed a new Oracle client. Thanks.

Comment: I assume this is app.config? any suggestion on how to vary it vs test env?

Answer (score 9):

To avoid all the Oracle mess of not knowing where it is looking for the TNSNAMES.ORA (I have the added confusion of multiple Oracle versions and 32/64 bit), you can copy the setting from your existing TNSNAMES.ORA to your own config file and use that for your connection.
Say you're happy with the 'DSDSDS' reference in TNSNAMES.ORA which maps to something like:

```
DSDSDS=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(Host=DSDSDSHost)(Port=4521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=DSDSDSService)))
```

You can take the text after the first '=' and use that wherever you are using 'DSDSDS' and it won't need to find TNSNAMES.ORA to know how to connect.
Now your connection string would look like this:

`string connectionString = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(Host=DSDSDSHost)(Port=4521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=DSDSDSService)));User Id=UNUNUN;Password=PWPWPW;";`

Comment: Where should I place Connection Timeout param inside that long munster?

Comment: All of the allowed attributes are separated by semicolons. The data source attribute is what makes it look like cousin It !   The Oracle docs have the full list of attributes (including Connection Timeout which you could just tack on the end after the last semicolon inside the doublequotes): https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/win.101/b10117/features001.htm

Comment: Easiest working solution for .Net 5 app !

Answer (score 4):

Once I found what format it was looking for in the connection string, it worked just fine like this with Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.  Without having to mess around with anything separately.

```
DATA SOURCE=DSDSDS:1521/ORCL;
```

Answer (score 3):

A "little" late to the party but the real answer to this - if you use `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess` ODP.NET provider, you should forget about things like `network\admin`, `Oracle client`, `Oracle_Home`, etc.

Here is what you need

1. Download and install *Oracle Developer Tools for VS* or *ODAC*. Note - Dev tools will install ODAC for you. This will create relatively small installation under `C:\Program Files (x86)`. With full dev tools, under 60Mb
2. In your project you will install Nuget package with corresponding version of ODP.net *(Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll)* which you will reference
3. At this point you have 2 options to connect.

   - a) In the connection string set `datasource` in the following format

     `DataSource=ServerName:Port/SID . . .` or `DataSource=IP:Port/SID . . .`
   - b) Create `tnsnames.ora` file (only it is going to be different from previous experiences). Have entry in it:

     > AAA = (DESCRIPTION = 
     >          (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = ServerNameOrIP)(PORT = 1521))
     >          (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME = SIDNAME)))

     And place this file into your bin folder, where your application is running from.
     Now you can connect using your connection name - `DataSource=AAA . . .` So, even though you have *tnsnames.ora*, with ODP.net *managed* it works a bit different - you create local TNS file. And now, it is easy to manage it.

To summarize - with *managed*, no need for heavy Oracle Client, `Oracle_home` or knowing depths of oracle installation folders. Everything can be done within your .net application structures.

Answer (score 2):

I had the similar issue......to solve this what I did was to uninstall the  ODP. Net and re-install in the same directory as oracle server......with server option you will notice that most of the products are already installed (while 12c database installation) so just select the other features and finally finish the installation....

Please note that this workaround works only if you have installed 12c on the same machine i.e. on your laptop............

If your database is located on the server machine other than your laptop then please select client option and not the server and then include TNS_ADMIN in your app.config and do not forget to specify the version...

since my installation is on my laptop so my App.config is as below:

```
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
            <configuration>
            <configSections>
            <section name="oracle.manageddataaccess.client" type="OracleInternal.Common.ODPMSectionHandler, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.122.21.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342"/>
            </configSections>
            <startup>
            <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.8"/>
            </startup>
            <system.data>
            <DbProviderFactories>
            <remove invariant="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client"/>
            <add name="ODP.NET, Managed Driver" invariant="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" description="Oracle Data Provider for .NET, Managed Driver" type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleClientFactory, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.122.21.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342"/>
            </DbProviderFactories>
            </system.data>
            <!-- Customize these connection alias settings to connect to Oracle DB -->
            <oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
            <version number="*">
            <dataSources>
            <dataSource alias="ORA19" descriptor="(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=XYZHOST)(PORT=999))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=XYZ))) "/>
            </dataSources>
            </version>
            </oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
            <connectionStrings>
            <clear />
            <!-- we use clear above to ignore the connection strings in machine.config file and redirect the Config reader to this file  -->
            <add name="ORA19"
            providerName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client"
            connectionString="(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=XYZHOST)(PORT=9999))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=XYZ)))" />
            </connectionStrings>  
            <runtime>
            <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral"/>
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0"/>
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Text.Json" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral"/>
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0"/>
            </dependentAssembly>
            </assemblyBinding>
            </runtime>
            </configuration>

            /////////the below code is a sample from oracle company////////////////


            using System;
            using System.Collections.Generic;
            using System.ComponentModel;
            using System.Data;
            using System.Data.Common;
            using System.Drawing;
            using System.Linq;
            using System.Text;
            using System.Threading.Tasks;
            using System.Windows.Forms;
            using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;

            ///copy these lines in a button click event 
            string constr = "User Id=system; Password=manager; Data Source=orcl;";
            // Click here and then press F9 to insert a breakpoint
            DbProviderFactory factory =
            DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client");
            using (DbConnection conn = factory.CreateConnection())
            {
            conn.ConnectionString = constr;
            try
            {
            conn.Open();
            OracleCommand cmd = (OracleCommand)factory.CreateCommand();
            cmd.Connection = (OracleConnection)conn;

            //to gain access to ROWIDs of the table
            //cmd.AddRowid = true;
            cmd.CommandText = "select * from all_users";

            OracleDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            int visFC = reader.VisibleFieldCount; //Results in 2
            int hidFC = reader.HiddenFieldCount;  // Results in 1

            MessageBox.Show(" Visible field count: " + visFC);

            MessageBox.Show(" Hidden field count: " + hidFC);


            reader.Dispose();
            cmd.Dispose();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            MessageBox.Show(ex.StackTrace);
            }
            }
```

Comment: I would have expected the config to have the node that you referenced in your answer?

Answer (score 1):

In my case everything said above was OK, but I still have been receiving `ORA-12545: Network Transport: Unable to resolve connect hostname`

I tried to ping the Oracle machine and found out I cannot see it and added it to the hosts file. Then I received another error message `ORA-12541: TNS:no listener`. After investigation I realized that pinging the same hostname from different machines getting different IP addresses(I don't know why) and I changed the IP address in my host file, which resolved the problem on 100%.

I'm bothering to write my experience as it seems obvious, but although I was sure the problem is in the above settings I totally forgot to check if I really can see the remote DB machine out there. Keep it in mind when you are out of ideas what is going on.....

These links helped me a lot:

http://www.moreajays.com/2013/03/ora-12545-connect-failed-because-target.html
http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/ORA-12541

Answer (score 1):

Just removing Oracle.ManagedDataAccess and leaving just Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core works for me.

Answer (score -1):

I received the same error message.  To resolve this I just replaced the `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess` assembly with the older `Oracle.DataAccess` assembly.  This solution may not work if you require new features found in the new assembly.  In my case I have many more higher priority issues then trying to configure the new `Oracle` assembly.