# Regarding Connecting to Oracle DB on Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, oracle11g

I am trying to create a test application using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 - .Net Framework 4 and would need some help to test connection with Oracle Database.

It is just that I have the Oracle Database hosted on a different server and I want to test the connection on my machine which has VS 2010 installed and is connected on the same network.

I am pretty new to Oracle and I have been informed that even without Oracle client installed on my machine I can still try and connect to the database using the Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll

I have ODP.NET_Managed121010 installed on this machine and tried an example from the below link http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/dotnet/vs2010-oracle-dev-410461.html

Only that, instead of using Oracle.DataAccess, I used Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.

I am sure there is something that I am missing or I could be wrong too. But any pointers on this would be really helpful.

Comment: Are you getting an error message?

Comment: Sorry- forgot to mention the exception messages. No such host is known ; TNS: could not resolve the connect identifier specified ; The source was not found, but some or all event logs could not be searched.

Comment: Do you have your data source defined in your TNS Names file?  Might be good to check http://stackoverflow.com/a/20050462/62640 to avoid any differences in the way the host gets resolved between DataAccess and ManagedDataAccess.