# ODP.NET Managed Data Access LDAP Configuration not working unless LDAP.ORA is included

Tags: .net, oracle, odp.net, odp.net-managed

For some reason I have to include an LDAP.ORA file inside my .NET project when attempting to connect to Oracle with LDAP.  From my understanding of using the [Oracle.ManagagedDataAccess](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess/) nuget package I should be able to contain everything within the web.config.  [Documentation from Oracle is located here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E51173_01/win.122/e17732/InstallConfig.htm#ODPNT8159) and a useful [walk through is provided here](http://errummwelluhh.blogspot.com/2014/02/using-oracle-odpnet-managed-driver-with.html).  I am guessing that one of my configuration properties is slightly off, but I haven't been able to track it down.  Any help would be much appreciated!

**Oracle Configuration Section**

```
  <oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
    <version number="*">
      <LDAPsettings>
        <LDAPsetting name="DIRECTORY_TYPE" value="OID" />
        <LDAPsetting name="DEFAULT_ADMIN_CONTENT" value="dc=mycompany,dc=net"/>
        <LDAPsetting name="DIRECTORY_SERVERS" value="(myoid.mycompany.net:1389:1636)" />
      </LDAPsettings>
      <settings>
        <setting name="NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH" value="(LDAP)"/>
        <setting name="NAMES.DEFAULT_DOMAIN" value="mycompany"/>
      </settings>
    </version>
  </oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
```

**Oracle Connection String**

```
<add name="MyDatabase" providerName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" connectionString="Data Source=MyDatabase; User Id=MyUser; Password=MyPassword;" />
```

**Connection Code**

```
private DbConnection GetConnection()
{
    var connectionStringSettings = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDatabase"];
    var connection = new OracleConnection(connectionStringSettings.ConnectionString);
    connection.Open();
    return connection;
}
```

Comment: There is a bug when ODP.NET Managed Driver used LDAP to resolve the TNS alias, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30905910/odp-net-managed-library-does-resolve-alias-but-32-bit-library-does/30920849 Perhaps this is related to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think

```
<LDAPsetting name="DIRECTORY_TYPE" value="OID" />
<LDAPsetting name="DEFAULT_ADMIN_CONTENT" value="dc=mycompany,dc=net"/>
```

must be replaced by

```
<LDAPsetting name="DIRECTORY_SERVER_TYPE" value="OID" />
<LDAPsetting name="DEFAULT_ADMIN_CONTEXT" value="dc=mycompany,dc=net"/>
```

I am not sure but I assume when your default context is `dc=mycompany,dc=net`, then your `NAMES.DEFAULT_DOMAIN` has to be `mycompany.net`.