# How to configure Entity Framework with LDAP?

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework, ldap, odp.net

I would like to have a sample code on how to set up a config file that allows EF to map entities from an Oracle DB over LDAP connection. Most of the documentation I have read agree about about the `<LDAPSetting>` tag but say nothing about the `<connectionStrings>` and/or `<entityFramework>` tags. So far, this is what I have got.

```xml
<oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
    <version number="*">
      <LDAPsettings>  
        <LDAPsetting name="DIRECTORY_SERVERS" value="(serverX:3060:3131,serverY:3060:3131,serverZ:3060:3131,serverQ:3060:3131)"/>  
        <LDAPsetting name="DIRECTORY_SERVER_TYPE" value="oid"/>  
        <LDAPsetting name="DEFAULT_ADMIN_CONTEXT" value="cn=OracleContext,dc=mydomain,dc=com"/>  
      </LDAPsettings>  
      <settings>  
        <setting name="NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH" value="(LDAP)"/>  
      </settings>      
    </version>
  </oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
```

Any sample will be a great help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading some documentation, I've noticed there are two ways of setting up LDAP. Therefore, it is not a matter of "should" but "which" works for you. As @Wernfried suggested I have used the `<setting>` tag and according to this [reference](https://docs.oracle.com/html/E41125_02/featConfig.htm#BABEGGHD) it's fine. However, for some reason I don't know it didn't work to me. Instead I left the initial `<LDAPsetting>` tag as pointed in **LDAPSettings section** [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E63277_01/win.121/e63268/InstallManagedConfig.htm#ODPNT8164) and it worked.

As to the `<connectionStrings>` it was as simple as follow:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="Source" connectionString= "Data Source=ServiceName;password=your_password;User ID=your_user" providerName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" />
</connectionStrings>
```

- **Source:** The name for the source.
- **ServiceName:** The Oracle Service you want to connect to.

As to the Entity Framework, I kept the default settings as configured by the NuGet package installer. In my projects I've installed the **Official Oracle ODP.NET, Managed Driver** and the **Official Oracle ODP.NET, Managed Entity Framework Driver** NuGet packages.

```
<entityFramework>
  <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
    <parameters>
      <parameter value="v12.0"/>
    </parameters>
  </defaultConnectionFactory>
  <providers>
    <provider invariantName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" 
            type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework.EFOracleProviderServices, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework, Version=6.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342"/>
  </providers>
</entityFramework>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check your syntax, it should be like this:

```
<oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
    <version number="*">
      <LDAPsettings>  
        <setting name="DIRECTORY_SERVERS" value="(serverX:3060:3131,serverY:3060:3131,serverZ:3060:3131,serverQ:3060:3131)"/>  
        <setting name="DIRECTORY_SERVER_TYPE" value="oid"/>  
        <setting name="DEFAULT_ADMIN_CONTEXT" value="cn=OracleContext,dc=mydomain,dc=com"/>  
      </LDAPsettings>  
     <settings>  
        <setting name="NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH" value="(LDAP)"/>  
      </settings>      
    </version>
  </oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
```

See [Configuring Oracle Data Provider for .NET](https://docs.oracle.com/html/E41125_02/featConfig.htm#sthref138) for more details.

Regarding LDAP and ODP.NET Managed Provider check also this issue: [ODP.NET Managed library does resolve alias, but 32-bit library does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30905910/odp-net-managed-library-does-resolve-alias-but-32-bit-library-does/30920849#30920849)

Comment: Thanks for your help with the configuration @wernfried-domscheit. As for the last link, I wish it could help but, unfortunately I am not using Oracle Client as ODP.NET Managed Driver is fully managed. Therefore, Oracle Client could be opt-out.
Also I would like your input on how to configure Entity Framework with the above LDAP settings. Thanks in advance.