# Use Entity Framework with existing ORACLE DB. Visual Studio 2012 and Deprecated ODP.NET Driver

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework, ldap, odp.net

I have done enough research but can't find an answer.

I have an Oracle DB which I am using with my ADO.NET and it is working fine. However, I would like to use it with Entity Framework 6. Since DB is already in place, I am not going to do "Code First" approach.
Below are the issues I am having. ***Please keep them in mind before jumping to a conclusion.***

- I have VS 2012 with Old ODP Driver. VS is asking me to upgrade. CANT
- I can't use EDM to generate Diagrams and Code, since I don't have latest ODAC installed and I don't get the option to connect to Oracle DB
- If I try to use the same connection string with EF which is working fine with ADO.NET then I get followig error

> ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified

Note I am using LDAP to connect to Oracle DB.

I also tried generating an empty EDM and added a new connection string as followed, then I got a different error.

```
<add name="EF" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl
                                |res://*/Model1.ssdl
                                |res://*/Model1.msl;
                                provider=Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;
                                provider connection string=&quot;data source=MY_SERVICE;password=MY_PASSWORD;persist security info=True;user id=MY_USERID&quot;"
                                providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

> The entity type  is not part of the model for the current
>   context.

My questions.

- Is there a workaround for above issues.
- Is there a way to Map Oracle TABLES, STORED PROCEDURES, FUNCTIONS etc. manually?

I know above doesn't make much sense but these are the constraints I have. I am trying to Avoid Long/Old ADO.NET code. If it cannot be done then it is fine as well.

Thanks in advance for your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not so clear what you problem is, because terms like "ODAC" or "ADO.NET" are quite ambiguous.

ODAC is a software package which contains several providers and drivers. Please state clearly the provider (e.g. `OraOLEDB.Oracle` or `MSDAORA`) and references (e.g. `Oracle.DataAccess.Client` or `System.Data.OracleClient`) and tell us which one is working or not working.

Anyway, it looks like you have problems with ODP.NET Managed Provider (`Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client`), so focus on that one. Apparently it does not find the `sqlnet.ora` and `ldap.ora` file.

Check following setting whether they point to correct location of these files:

1. data source alias in the `dataSources` section under `<oracle.manageddataaccess.client>` section in the .NET config file.
2. data source alias in the `tnsnames.ora` file at the location specified by `TNS_ADMIN` in the .NET config file. Locations can consist of either absolute or relative directory paths.
3. data source alias in the `tnsnames.ora` file present in the same directory as the `.exe`.

Note, unlike other providers ODP.NET Managed Provider does **not** read any Registry settings and does not read environment variable.

There have been a [bug reported](https://community.oracle.com/message/13141200) that ODP.NET Managed Provider does not resolve alias from LDAP, see this workaround: [ODP.NET Managed library does resolve alias, but 32-bit library does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30905910/odp-net-managed-library-does-resolve-alias-but-32-bit-library-does/30920849#30920849)

Comment: Thank you for reply. I know what ODAC and ADO.NET are. If you look at my question again you will notice that I had no problem connecting with ADO.NET, but I wanted to use EF 6. Plus I use LDAP so tnsnames.ora is out of context for the discussion. Having said that I was able to connect to DB. However, at that point I am not sure how I can tell EF 6 Framework that I would like to use Database First Model (without having the ability to use EDM). I also saw Migration  table in DB so for sure it is using Code First I believe.
Thanks again for your input.

Comment: Well, actually the rule should be more precise saying "data source alias, resp. references in the `sqlnet.ora` and `tnsnames.ora` or `ldap.ora` files ..."