# Can ODP.NET support LDAP with the Entity Frameworks tools?

Tags: oracle, entity-framework, visual-studio-2017, ldap

Does anyone know if ODP.NET Managed Access (Oracle.ManagedDataAccess 12.2) support LDAP with the Entity Frameworks tools (vs 2017 Entity Framework 6.2)?  The DBA inhibited access through TNS, so I no longer unable to connect to database to update the data models.  The error message I received was ORA-12154 TNS could not resolve the connect identifier specified.

I tried to include the LDAPSetting in the app.net, but that didn't work.  Is there any way I could still use the Entity Framework tools to update these data models?

Comment: Did you set any `TNS_ADMIN` environment variable? This takes precedence over settings in app.net file.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the ODP.NET Managed Driver does not find your `sqlnet.ora` and `ldap.ora` files.

Did you set `NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH = (LDAP, ...)` in your `sqlnet.ora` file?

You can define location of `sqlnet.ora` and `ldap.ora` files also by `TNS_ADMIN` environment variable or in machine.config with a script similar to this:

```
set TNS_ADMIN=C:\oracle\network\admin

set Oracle_x64=c:\oracle\product\12.2\Client_x64\odp.net
"%Oracle_x64%\managed\x64\OraProvCfg.exe" /action:config /product:odpm /frameworkversion:v4.0.30319 /providerpath:%Oracle_x64%\managed\common\Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll /set:settings\TNS_ADMIN:%TNS_ADMIN%


set Oracle_x86=c:\oracle\product\12.2\Client_x86\odp.net
"%Oracle_x86%\managed\x86\OraProvCfg.exe" /action:config /product:odpm /frameworkversion:v4.0.30319 /providerpath:%Oracle_x86%\managed\common\Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll /set:settings\TNS_ADMIN:%TNS_ADMIN%
```

If it does not help, here would be a workaround: [ODP.NET Managed library does resolve alias, but 32-bit library does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30905910/odp-net-managed-library-does-resolve-alias-but-32-bit-library-does/30920849#30920849). However, on my machine LDAP resolution works fine with ODP.NET Managed Driver. Perhaps have also a look at [Oracle Data Provider for .NET, Managed Driver Configuration](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E63277_01/win.121/e63268/InstallManagedConfig.htm#ODPNT8159)

Comment: Thank you Wernfried for the details on LDAP.  My issue is mainly with the Entity Framework Update Wizard.  I built a number of Data Models using the Entity Framework Tool when I was still able to connect to my Oracle Database using TNS connection string.  Now that we moved to LDAP, I am unable to connect to the Oracle database using the Wizard to update the Models.  It appears the Update Wizard only supports TNS and EZConnect.  Any idea how I could make the Update Wizard recognize the LDAP settings?  Thank you.

Comment: Did you set `TNS_ADMIN` environment variable? What is the content of `sqlnet.ora` file?