# Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core and ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied

Tags: c#, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-manageddataaccess

I'm trying to connect to the oracle server (11g) with `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core 2.19.50` but receiving ORA-01017 error.

Current settings:

```
            OracleConfiguration.DirectoryServers = "(oid2.COMPANY.com:389:636, oid1.COMPANY.com:389:636)";
            OracleConfiguration.DirectoryType = @"OID";
            OracleConfiguration.DefaultAdminContext = @"dc=COMPANY,dc=com";
            OracleConfiguration.NamesDirectoryPath = "(LDAP, TNSNAMES)";
            OracleConfiguration.SqlNetAuthenticationServices = "(NONE)";

            OracleConfiguration.StatementCacheSize = 25;
            OracleConfiguration.BindByName = true;
            OracleConfiguration.CommandTimeout = 300;
            OracleConfiguration.FetchSize = 1024 * 1024;

            OracleConfiguration.TraceOption = 1;
            OracleConfiguration.TraceLevel = 7;
            OracleConfiguration.TraceFileLocation = @"C:\Temp";
            OracleConfiguration.SendBufferSize = 8192;
            OracleConfiguration.ReceiveBufferSize = 8192;
            OracleConfiguration.DisableOOB = true;
```

I've tried different `SqlNetAuthenticationServices` options, read traces (didn't find anything useful there).

Connection:

```
           using var connection =
                new OracleConnection(
                    $@"Data Source={this._system.DbName};Persist Security Info=False;",
                    new OracleCredential(userName, securePassword, OracleDBAPrivilege.None)
                );
```

At the same time SQL Navigator which is using regular `windows Oracle client v11.2.0.4.0` works fine and can login (on the same machine).

I'm not an Oracle expert, but it looks like I miss some settings from client (which was installed here before me), do You have any suggestions where to look for a settings or may be I miss something.

*P.S. as you can see from above - I've already extracted some settings from client settings like LDAP server names.*

Comment: Maybe check this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52271114/can-odp-net-support-ldap-with-the-entity-frameworks-tools/52272021#52272021

Comment: LDAP part works just fine, but the login process does not. Also, this is the answer for `ODP.NET`, not for `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core`.

Comment: From my point of view - `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core` should not reference any system-defined parameters or filles to get it working. Previously I've had an issue with server name resolution, but `Directory*` options resolved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some investigation I've discovered that `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core` [do not support](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/dotnet/ODPNET_Core_get_started/index.html) **11g** version of the server. And that's pretty much it, I've to readjust my project for 3rd party solution for Oracle DB connection.

*Shame on the Oracle backward compatibility.*