# Find out where oracle.manageddataaccess searching tnsnames.ora

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, oracle, odp.net, tnsnames

I migrated my web application from unmanaged to managed Oracle Data Provider  (ODP.NET)

```
Oracle.DataAccess.dll => Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll
```

As the web application uses the `tnsnames.ora` file, and it seems the managed dll is not registry friendly, just changing the dll and renaming the references gave the `ORA-12545: Network Transport: Unable to resolve connect hostname`; after reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20050462/961631) I put the `tnsnames.ora` in the main website directory and the connection were successful.

But if remove the tnsnames from the web application folder and put the environment variable "TNS_ADMIN" at the local  path, the connection does not work...

If I remove the "tnsnames.ora" file from the web application folder, add the `TNS_ADMIN` environment variable and the path to it (`C:\oracle\product\11.2.0\client_1\Network\Admin`), I then open the ProcessMonitor (as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28283924/961631)), add a filter *Path=>contains=> tnsnames*, and reload my local web application, the processmonitor dont't find any activity on this filter, and the connection to oracle fails...

Is there a way to find out, what is the path the Oracle dll is trying to load?

Comment: Did you read my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28280883/determining-location-of-relevant-tnsnames-ora-file/28283924#28283924 ? There I provided the search path and a link to *Process Monitor*. This tool shows you which file your application is trying to load.

Comment: I removed the tnsnames from the web application folder, added the TNS_ADMIN environment variable and the path to it, as in the OP, then opened ProcessMonitor, added a filter path contains tnsnames, and reloaded my local web application, however the processmonitor did't find any activity on this event...

Comment: Strange, according to my knowledge it should take the TNS_ADMIN variable. Did you configure TNS_ADMIN in your .net config file? You can edit the file manually or use the `OraProvCfg.exe` file in your Oracle folder.